# PHP EACH ELEMENT IS NOT SUPPORT IN PHP8

Tags: php, foreach, wordpress-theming, php-8

Is not working on php8

`each` function is removed on php8

```
list($orig,$values) = each($where);
```

Full code:

```
if ($custom = apply_filters("pe_theme_metabox_$type",$pmboxes)) {
    //print_r(array_keys(PeGlobal::$config["metaboxes-view"]));
    $keys = array_keys($custom);
    foreach ($keys as $key) {
        $metaboxes[$key] = $custom[$key];
        $where =& $metaboxes[$key]["where"];
        list($orig,$values) = each($where);
        if ($orig != $type) {
            unset($where[$orig]);
            $where[$type] = $values;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, you are right, it was removed. What is your question?

Comment: It's not even clear why you're using `each()` in this code, since you reassign `$where` each time through the loop. It looks like you're using it to get the first key/value in the array.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a general replacement for `each()`, but since this code will not repeatedly use it on the same array, you don't need a complete replacement. This code is just getting the first key and value of each `$metaboxes[$key]["where"]` array, not looping through all the values. So you can do:

```
$orig = array_keys($where)[0];
$values = $where[$orig];
```

Comment: Thank you very much now Is working